# Как записать число в файл так, чтобы целая и дробная части были отделены запятой в Python?

Tags: python

Добрый день.

Пересел на мак, в нем есть прекрасная (среди бесплатных) программа Grapher, но вот беда: импорт из файла осуществляется только в том случае, когда дробная и целая часть чисел записаны через запятую (например, `'2,23'` для числа `2.23`).

Так вот вопрос: можно ли записывать в файл числа сразу через запятую (они естественно хранятся в массиве). Или кто работает на Grapher может уже как нибудь решил эту проблему?

Comment: Они хранятся в списке? В каком виде?

Comment: Да, можно. Покажите код, который записывает данные в файл.

Comment: Например,  i1.write('%f %f\n' % (a[0][0],a[1][0])).

Answer (score 2):

Меняем локаль, потом преобразуем число в строку:

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'rus')
print(locale.format('%.2f', 2.23))  # выведет 2,23
```

В вашем случае вместо вывода на экран аналогично форматируете число и записываете в файл.

Вариант `'rus'` проверен на Windows 10 на Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.6.

Информация ниже основана на данном ответе: [Python locale error: unsupported locale setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14548156/4752653)

Если используете *nix систему, и вариант `'rus'` не срабатывает, смотрите вывод команды `locale -e`, и выбираете подходящий вариант. К примеру, вывод команды на Linux Mint 18.2:

```
insolor@LMint182 ~ $ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
ru_RU.utf8
```

Подходящая локаль здесь - `ru_RU.utf8`.

## Дополнение

В Python3 можно использовать стандартный метод строки `format`:

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'rus')
print('{:n}'.format(1.23))  # 1,23
```

`n` как раз отвечает за отображение числа с текущими настройки локали, см. [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Comment: Это имя локали будет на OS X работать?

Comment: @jfs, хороший вопрос. По идее оно стандартное (т.е. имена локалей более-менее стандартизованы), и все должно работать, но мне не на чем протестировать.

Comment: у меня win и выводит ошибку: locale.Error: unsupported locale setting

Comment: @KtoTo, какая версия Python?

Comment: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'rus') -- надо было так! Версия 3.6

Comment: @KtoTo, да, действительно, на 3.6 ошибка. Поправлю ответ.