# Варианты записи чисел через запятую

Tags: python, python-3.x

записываю массив чисел float в .csv файл и открываю через Excel.
Python записывает числа через точку. Excel считает вещественными те числа, которые записаны через запятую.
Какие самые простые способы записывать в файл числа через запятую?
У меня 2 вариантa.

```
# Первый вариант
a = 4.2342342326
str(a).replace('.',',')    # OUT: '4,2342342326'

#второй вариант
with open('input.txt', 'r+') as f:
    txt = f.read().replace('.', ',')
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.write(txt)
```

Второй вариант оказался самый удобный, тк не надо ничего переделывать. "import locale" - не оправдал моих ожиданий, тк стандартный format все так же пишет числа через точку.

Comment: Дополнил в своем ответе [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705322/1365) про использование стандартного метода строки `format`.

Comment: куда в код я должен добавить строку "locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'rus')" что бы заработало? У меня в консоли в питоне переводит локаль, а внутри кода(вызвал ф-цию setlocale перед открытием файла) не работает.

Comment: что именно не работает? У меня нормально работает.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

```
a = 4.2342342326

str(a).replace('.',',')
```

Comment: спасибо, у себя подправил

Answer (score 1):

```
import locale

a = 4.2342342326
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'rus')
print(locale.format('%.10f', a))  # 4,2342342326
```

Comment: а нельзя использовать стандартный format? или использовать local.format('{}',a)